# Forcing x-axis to display all the days within the zoom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working on a highstock chart where I need to plot the number of connections made every day to the application (type: column).

Is there a way to force the x-axis to show every day within the zoom even if the series does not contain values for some day? I'd rather achieve so through highstock settings than passing 0 for each missing day.

My current setting is

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // daily
  minRange: 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // 3 days
},
```

And the chart skips the days without connections.

Thanks for your help.

Sig

Answer (score 0):

Set `tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/9xEQQ/